# Complete program hang when trying to call ReadLine()

Tags: c#, sockets, freeze

Consider the following:

```
    private void Read()
    {
        StreamReader r = new StreamReader(clientObject.GetStream());
        string str = r.ReadLine();
        if ((str == null) || (str == "")) { Disconnect(); }
        Client_dataReceived(str);

        Read();
    }
```

When I connect this client to a server, it hangs. When I break it with Intellisense, 
"string str = r.ReadLine();" is highlighted, I assume this is what the program was working on just before it started hanging. Why does it hang like this? I have created applications previously the exact same way, they don't hang.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
I just tried this:

```
    private void Read()
    {
        StreamReader r = new StreamReader(clientObject.GetStream());
        string str;
        while ((str = r.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            Client_dataReceived(str);
        }
    }
```

But I get the same effect...

Comment: Maybe it never returns a null string, breaking the second example. Remember that null and empty are two distinct values.

Comment: Isn't `ReadLine` blocking? Does the server send at least a line of data?

Comment: It should be sending data... I'll check this though, as its all I have left.

Comment: What is clientObject? Not all streams behave the same way when you reach the end.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is a recursive call with no exit. You call Read inside of Read. It does not matter where it breaks.

```
private void Read()
{
    StreamReader r = new StreamReader(clientObject.GetStream());
    string str = r.ReadToEnd();
    if ((str == null) || (str == "")) { Disconnect(); }
    Client_dataReceived(str);
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Read lines of data sent through and then pass it to the Client_dataReceived void for it to be parsed. Recursively, I mean.

Comment: You need to loop thru the Stream to get all the data.

Comment: Unfortunately, exact same issue... Thanks anyway

Comment: My application still hangs. I usually have some idea of what's wrong, but lately, any networking project I do ends up like this.

Comment: Debugging it now - what does it do? And your not calling Read from inside of Read are you?

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Read()
    {
        StreamReader r = new StreamReader(clientObject.GetStream());
        string str;
        while (!(String.IsNullOrEmpty(str=r.ReadLine())))
        {
            Client_dataReceived(str);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a recursive call.  You will eventually get a StackOverflowException. (How coincidental. I just realized that!)

Try this:

```
 private void Read()
    {
        using (var r = new StreamReader(clientObject.GetStream()))
        {
            string str;
            while ((str = r.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                Client_dataReceived(str);
            }
            Disconnect();
        }
    }
```

NOTE:  I intentionally removed your str == "" test, as returning an empty string doesn't mean you've read to the end of the stream, while a null return does.  If you have a special case where the empty line is important to be triggered on, be sure to restore that test.

Now if the clientObject is something that waits for input, like a TcpClient, then you need to evaluate it differently.  It would help if we knew what clientObject was.

Comment: Yes, it hangs here "while ((str = r.ReadLine()) != null)"

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment because of low reputation so I'm writing it here...

Try adding a `return();` statement after `disconnect();` in your first code snippet.